# How to maintain synchronised state across threads - is this a good use for a Singleton?

Tags: design-patterns, multithreading, singleton

I hear a lot about "Singletons are always bad" around the place. I don't hate on them to that degree but I try not to use them if I have a better alternative.

In this case I have a system that handles a lot of requests, each of which comes in on its own thread. Every request that comes in needs to be allocated its own unique sequential Id.

Currently I have a Singleton class whose role is to initiate this Id at start-up then maintain it while the system runs. The Singleton is created/retrieved and the Id value incremented in a thread safe way, as one would expect. It is actually handed out to the threads on creation by Dependency Injection, but the core of the class is a classic Singleton built around a static representation of the current Id value.

Given that we are only likely to do more work that requires a multi-threaded approach, I would be interested to know whether there is a way I could implement this type of functionality in a way that allows data to be maintained synchronously across threads that are otherwise unaware of each other, without using the much feared Singleton pattern?

Comment: It seems like you are using the Singleton pattern precisely how it should be used.  Unless you need to start scaling your application across multiple (virtual or real) machines, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: How will it work with multiple servers? Do you need to keep ID of request unique in global state or only inside one process?

Comment: @OZ_ the design is currently oriented towards a single machine- although the system will operate on multiple ones there is no need for the ID to be unique across machines, just within the application.

Comment: It's not clear that singleton means what you think it means.  Are you calling its `getInstance()` then injecting the result?  It's also not clear why the current Id would need to be static, if you only have one instance of the class.  Could you post some code?

Comment: Is it only a singleton if you obtain it by getInstance? I am using checked instantiation so there is a single static implementation of the class returned when it is called, but I don't have an explicit getInstance method. Is this behaviour significantly different?

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between a singleton and an instance that can be shared between multiple clients. You seem to want the latter (if not, think again!). For that, a singleton has no advantage and many of the usual downsides. Just permit any number of instances, but don't actually create several ones when you *want* sharing. You already have the infrastructure right for this (passing the object via dependency injection). You probably only need to make the constructor public and get rid of the singleton infrastructure.

So it costs practically nothing, and you gain:

- Simplicity: Luckily, *not* making something a singleton is slightly easier than making it a singleton.
- Testability: When you want to test something involving this ID allocator, you can just create a new one instead of depending on some global state of some singleton.
- Extensibility: Should you at one point need several independent sources of sequential IDs in one process, you can just create another instance.

Comment: How do I guarantee that the different instances are only handing out unique and sequential ids? My singleton is already implementing an interface for DI/mocking purposes, so there isn't a problem with testing things that use it.

Comment: @glenatron You don't. The whole point is allowing (or rather, not explicitly prohibiting!) several *completely independent* instances. When you need multiple places (e.g. server threads) to get unique and sequential IDs w.r.t. to each other, you give them the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

By having a singleton, you're then adding the singleton creation, access and state manipulation to your multithreading concerns.

Further, you're assuming that your request handler is going to only have one in the entire system. This is incorrect. Yes, you might only need one now. But what about unit tests? Are you really **not** going to run them concurrently? What about sub-systems that may eventually want their own request dispatch? What about possibly decorating or compositing that dispatch?

No, you have some object that takes requests and assigns them an ID for that handler. If they change scopes, then you can either simply re-ID the request or have a single shared ID provider for your different request handlers.

Comment: creation can be done pre thread start-up (eager initialization) and state manip is just InterleavedIncrement

Comment: @ratchetfreak - the entire point of a singleton rather than a simple global/static is to ignore creation timing. If you then limit it to thread start-up, what's the point. And I means state of the singleton, not the ID; I'll look to clarify the answer.